# How to only display message when redirected from a certain webpage

Tags: python, flask

I am working on CS50 web's final project, finance, and am trying to have a feature where a message bought will only be displayed when redirected from a certain webpage. To be specific, I want to display a message "Bought!" when a user is redirected from the buy page (buy.html), and a "Sold!" message when redirected from the sold page (sell.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
# your code.....
return render_template('message.html', msg="Bought!")
```

Then, in message.html:

```
{{ msg }}
```

or

```
{% if msg == "Bought!" %}
    <span class="bigGreenLetters">You bought it!</span>
{% elif msg == "Sold!" %}
    <span class="bigRedLetters">You sold it!</span>
{% endif %}
```

The above leaves them at the same URL (I would prefer that).  If you really want to redirect them:

```
return redirect(url_for('message', msg=msg="Bought!"))
```

with:

```
@app.route('/message')
def message():
    # do stuff
    return render_template('message.html', msg=msg)
```